# Trying to remove path, file extension and, if present, a certain query parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm fairly new to .htaccess, but have gotten close to what I need, but am now stuck.

Input: `https://www.example.com/p/mypage.html`

Output: `https://www.example.com/mypage`

This is achieved with the following:

```
# Static pages: Remove /p from path and remove .html
RewriteRule ^p(/.*?)(?:\.html)?$ $1 [R=301,L]
# All other posts just remove .html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)\.html?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

However, very often there is a query parameter m=1 that needs removed IF IT IS PRESENT

I need that query parameter removed for both static pages AND other posts in the above RewriteRules.  Note that there very often may be other query parameters also present but that I do not want those to be removed.

**Example 1:**

Input: `https://www.example.com/p/mypage.html?param1=a&m=1&param2=b`

DESIRED output: `https://www.example.com/mypage?param1=a&param2=b`

**Example 2:**

Input: `https://www.example.com/2019/12/mypage.html?param1=a&m=1&param2=b`

DESIRED output: `https://www.example.com/2019/12/mypage?param1=a&param2=b`

In both of the above examples, all of the following are removed:

- `/p` if present
- `.html` if present
- `m=1` if present (sometimes it may be the only query parameter so that also needs taken into account)

(By the way, the above three bullets will be useful for anyone moving a site over from Blogger / Blogspot to Wordpress, as they represent the differences in how the paths and pages are handled)

Very much appreciate any help with the `m=1` being removed if present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this rule to remove a query parameter if present and remove `/p` or `.html` as well.

Here is your complete .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(.*&)?m=1&?(\S*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:p/)?(.+)(?:\.html)?$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,NE,NC,L]

# Static pages: Remove /p from path and remove .html
RewriteRule ^p(/.*?)(?:\.html)?$ $1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]

# All other posts just remove .html
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you!  Can you help me understand what your RewriteCond line is doing?  I see the \sHTTP in it and I already have lines before in my file:  `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`  Also, will this also git rid of the m=1 in your last line above? (I'd like it to)

Comment: Sorry I had a typo, fixed it now. It matches `m=1` in a query string.

Comment: Seems to work pefectly!  I check in all scenarios I could think of:  with or without /p, with or without .html, with or without m=1, passing no query parameters, passing lots of query parameters (sometimes with and sometimes without m=1 as one of them).  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written as per shown samples. Also please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
# Static pages: Remove /p from path and remove .html
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^p(/.*?)(?:\.html)?$ $1 [R=301,L]

# All other posts just remove .html
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)\.html?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

#Check if URI has .html with query string present in it.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(?:/p)?/(.*)\.html\?(.*)(?:[&?])m=1(.*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1?%2%3 [R=301,L]
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case you are looking for specifically only param1 and param2 parameters then try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
# Static pages: Remove /p from path and remove .html
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^p(/.*?)(?:\.html)?$ $1 [R=301,L]

# All other posts just remove .html
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)\.html?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

#Check if URI has .html with query string present in it.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(?:/p)?/(.*)\.html\?(param1=[^&]*)(?:[?&])m=1(param2=[^\s]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1?%2%3 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I think your 1st solution is VERY close to what I need. Thank you. For clarification, the m=1 query parameter may sometimes be the first one and sometimes the second, third and so on So it will sometimes show `?m=1` and sometimes `&m=1` and in either case it needs removed.  And I would want to preserve ALL other query parameters, if present.  How would I add that please?

Comment: @l_r, your welcome could you please try my edited 1st solution now? I have made it to look for `?m` or `&m` kindly do let me know how it goes. For all other parameters it should catch them I believe, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I was able to get all scenarios to work with the answer from @anubhava (so I didn't fully test whether your solution worked in all scenarios).  Really appreciate the help from this community.

Comment: @l_r, Your welcome, we all learn from each other :) anubhava is GURU of apache, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: @l_r, Hello, I have tested rules(1st solution) with links `https://www.example.com/p/mypage.html?param1=a&m=1&param2=b` AND `https://www.example.com/2019/12/mypage.html?param1=a&m=1&param2=b` and it worked for both of them, could you please do let me on which case its not working with sample links please, just want to fix it for your other cases, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following rule to remove `m=1` query perameter from your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*?)&?(?:\bm=1)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R,L]
```